# Selenium IDE float multiplication in javascript returns 1 instead of 1,99

Tags: javascript, selenium, decimal

In selenium IDE i have a javascript evaluation that should multiply 3 decimal values.

```
javascript{parseFloat(storedVars['val1'])*parseFloat(storedVars['val2'])*parseFloat(storedVars['val3'])}
```

The code however only gives me 1 back,

> Executing: |store | javascript{parseFloat(storedVars['val1'])*parseFloat(storedVars['val2'])*parseFloat(storedVars['val3'])} | couponOdds |
>
> [info] Executing: |echo | Total odds value: ${val1} *${val2} *${val3}
>   = ${couponOdds} | | [info] echo: Total odds value: 1,02 *1,50 *1,30 = 1

How can i make the calculation work?

Comment: Side note: `1.02 * 1.5 * 1.3` = `1.989`, not `1.99`, unless you do rounding (as we're writing in English, I've used `.` as a decimal point there; I *think* the only locales where the decimal point is `,` are ones not using English as the primary language).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your quoted output, I think the problem is that you're using `,` rather than `.` as a decimal point, as is the case in several locales. [`parseFloat`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.3) only uses the `.`, not the `,`, as a decimal point.

So perhaps:

```
javascript{parseFloat(storedVars['val1'].replace(/,/g, "."))*parseFloat(storedVars['val2'].replace(/,/g, "."))*parseFloat(storedVars['val3'].replace(/,/g, "."))}
```

...although having `localeParseFloat` or something instead would probably be cleaner than doing the replace every time.